# How to convert multiple yolo darknet format into .csv file

Tags: python, yolov5

First I have Yolo darknet around 321 txt files. Each file contain of text 5 or 6 row.
as example below.

```
1 0.778906 0.614583 0.0828125 0.0958333
0 0.861719 0.584375 0.0984375 0.10625
0 0.654688 0.6 0.14375 0.125
0 0.254687 0.663542 0.146875 0.139583
0 0.457031 0.64375 0.120312 0.108333
0 0.960938 0.566667 0.078125 0.129167
```

(First column : 1 or 0 is class and another columns is coordinate x,y,w,h)

I try to convert to a csv file and I found solution as below.

```
os.chdir(r'C:\xxx\labels')
myFiles = glob.glob('*.txt') 
width=1024
height=1024
image_id=0
final_df=[]
for item in myFiles:
    row=[]
    bbox_temp=[]
    with open(item, 'rt') as fd:
        first_line = fd.readline()
        splited = first_line.split();
        
        row.append(fd.readline(1))
        row.append(width)
        row.append(height)
        try:
            bbox_temp.append(float(splited[1])*width)
            bbox_temp.append(float(splited[2])*height)
            bbox_temp.append(float(splited[3])*width)
            bbox_temp.append(float(splited[4])*height)
            row.append(bbox_temp)
            final_df.append(row)
        except:
            print("file is not in YOLO format!")
df = pd.DataFrame(final_df,columns=['image_id', 'width', 'height','bbox'])
df.to_csv("saved.csv",index=False)
```

and got output.

[image]

But this code make CSV file only first line of Yolo Darknet txt.
I want to get all of row (5 or 6 row for each text file.)

If code is work. CSV should has 321* 5 or 6 = 1,xxx rows x 4 columns.

Please help me for adjust this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just replace `first_line = fd.readline()` with `for first_line in fd.readlines():` and indent the remainder of the code?
You may also need to move `row=[]` and `bbox_temp=[]` into the new for loop.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's work. If I'd like to add each filename to new column. Can you help me again.

Comment: I think it'd just be a matter of adding `row.append(item)` at the end of the new for loop and naming the new column.

Comment: I try to do that and new column have only (filename : xxx_99.txt) all of row. But my data is xxx_1.txt - xxx_321.txt.

Comment: now I cannot input filename in dataframe. If you have any suggest or recommend please supporting.